# Laurent's series for a specific fraction

Tags: complex-analysis

How can we expand $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z^2 +1)}$ in a Laurent series valid for $|z-3|>2$ ?? My problem here is that that fraction will involve things like $(z+i)$ and $(z-i)$ but where is $z-3$??

Comment: $f$ is analytic in $|z-3| \lt |3-i|$ where it can be expanded to a Taylor series. So are you actually looking for the series in $|z-3| \gt |3-i|$?

Comment: I don't understand please explain

Comment: $f$ has singularities in $|z-3| \gt 2$ so it can't have a Laurent series which converges there

Comment: How about a Taylor series ??

Comment: You can expand it to a Taylor series in $|z-3| \lt 2$, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes , my book says find an expansion , but it was under the Laurent's series ...so I guess Taylor ??

Comment: can you please update the question with the region of convergence you are looking for?